# Tendermint Networks, what is the parameter before @?

Tags: tendermint

When I use the Tendermint Networks like this:

> tendermint node --p2p.persistent_peers "429fcf25974313b95673f58d77eacdd434402665@10.11.12.13:46656,96663a3dd0d7b9d17d4c8211b191af259621c693@10.11.12.14:46656"

What does the part before the @ sign mean?

Answer (score 4):

It's node identifier (ID), which is used to identify peers in a p2p network.

Node ID is derived from the private key, which can be found at `config/node_key.json`.

You can use `tendermint show_node_id` command to show current node ID or `tendermint gen_node_key` to generate a new node key.